# Wix File Name with hyphen

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I am including a file in Wix installer. The file has hyphen in it's name.

```
<File Name="my_file-with-hyphen-A.txt" Source="MyFolder\my_file-with-hyphen-A.txt" />
```

However when I look in cab file, the file is stored with the changed name of "my_file_with_hyphen_A.txt" i.e. hyphens are changed to underscore by Wix.

Another issue is that if I set the Id attribute of File element, the file name in cab is same as Id attribute. Shouldn't file name in cab be the same as Name attribute?

```
<File Id="myfilewithhyphenB" Name="my_file-with-hyphen-B.txt" Source="MyFolder\my_file-with-hyphen-B.txt" />
```

In last case the file name in cab is "myfilewithhyphenB".

I am using VS2012 and Wix 3.8 (I updated to Wix 3.9.16.0 and still have same issue). My question is how to include a file with hyphen?

Comment: Is this an issue? I'm guessing when the file is installed it has the correct name?

Comment: It gets installed fine. However I sent someone an installer for demoing the software. I was told that she does not have permission to run intaller. I told her to extract the cab file and run it. (For now installer is just dumping files). I was told back that a dll is missing and that's when I realized the hyphen in dll's name is not preserved and couldn't find any source why?

Comment: Not sure about getting the hyphenated name in the .cab file. As a workaround you may be able to build the installer as a per-user installer (you would have to change installation directory to something accessible to the user such as user's documents folder and change the package element's InstallScope attribute to "per-user") but it may be easier to just use a .zip utility to compress the actual files and send it to the person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to extract the cab without installing it is to create an "admin image".  To do this run `msiexec /a file.msi TARGETDIR=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\AdminImage.`

Answer (score 2):

Yes an "admin" install would help you out here. I've had this happen and I believe it's because when you MSZIP these resource files to cab files the cab file follow ISO9660 therefore "-"hyphen/dash characters are not permitted and are changed to "_" underscores.